# How can i take input from a html form and add to to a python script

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html

i have this script for summarizing text and want to take the input from html text fields to input it to the script and them show the results on the page.

i currently have

```
title = raw_input('Type a title for the text here:')
content = raw_input('Type the text to be summarized here:')
```

how can i change this to get the input from the html form?

```
Title:< input type = "text>
Content:< input type = "text>
```

Comment: Is this in the context of a website, or do you want to use an offline webpage?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: to make it easier to use the script on possibly put it online

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what do you mean when you say you want it as an offline webpage. You will need to use a server to handle that. This article here: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html explains such a system. Once you are ready to put this on a server, you may take a look at http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex51.html on how to handle web-forms with python.